# Peltier suddenly stopped working

Tags: peltier

I set up a device with a Peltier module squished between a small and a large heat sink. The large heat sink is on the hot side, and the small one is on the cold side.
I was running the device on 12v, and left it running for an hour. The cold side was definitely cold, as water was condensing on it. Ice even formed on it.

The next day, I turn it on and run it again. Water condensed, but didn’t form ice. So, I set the voltage to 14v and leave it for another hour.
I come back to a room temperature heat sink.

The device does not change temperature when connected to a power source, and my current meter reads nothing through it either. (Current draw is normally 3-5A)

So I cut it apart and peel the halves apart, and one of the little metal cubes inside is black and burn marks surround it.

Could someone tell me what happened here?
How can I design my system to get cold enough to make ice, but not use more power than it can handle?
Why did the module stop working? Is it destroyed?
Is there anything I should change about my design?

Comment: You probably should have been paying more attention to how hot the hot side was rather than how cold the cold was. Get some temperature measurement tools.

Comment: You burned it up.  Next time either use less power or provide better cooling or possibly both.  Consulting the datasheet and/or measuring temperatures while running the device can probably give you a good idea which you need to improve most.

Comment: I don’t have a constant current power source, and I was using a large heat sink. The hot sides heatsink was only getting slightly warm. I didn’t use any thermal paste though, but I did make sure it was pressed tightly against the heatsink.

Comment: @Proxy303 You should use thermal paste anyway - any computer parts store will have it. No idea if that was the problem - could be, could be not.

Comment: Also what's the rated voltage and current?

Comment: Rated at 12v, 15v max, 6A max current. I was running it at 14v at 4.5A.

Comment: However, it is also important to note that this one peltier device has been through a lot. It has been run in open air with no heatsink in the past, and has also been run momentarily on 24v as well.

Answer (score -1):

It definitely burned the path and now you have an open circuit (hence no current). Why don't you use a constant current source (something like an LED driver). Due to the different temperatures, your current consumption will change. So having a constant voltage source might lead to damage. You could also add an overcurrent protection module or something. Try using something like this: https://robu.in/product/lm2596-buck-step-power-converter-module-dc-4-040-1-3-37v-led-voltmeter/

Comment: My power supply is a CC/CV power supply. It runs in CV mode by default, with an adjustable voltage. You can also set the current limit, and when that current limit is reached, it switches into CC mode and the voltage drops.

Comment: I would suggest reading the module's datasheet and trying to set the current limit at the rated current in the datasheet. Set the CC limit to rated current in order to avoid damage.